# MYSQL unique VS php SELECT then insert.. Which is faster?

Tags: mysql, unique

Which is faster If I want to maintain a unique field in a table

Running a select query then insert query

OR directly running an insert query but have a unique field in the table instead

Comment: A single query runs faster than two queries, don't you think?

Comment: Try it. My guess is the single query will be way faster. In addition, having it as a table definition is the correct way to put that kind of domain information.

Comment: If you have a field than needs to contain unique values then you **must** put an `UNIQUE INDEX` on it. Otherwise it won't be unique for too long. And if you already have this constraint in the database, what's the point of working again to achieve it from PHP. Not to mention that, because of the concurrent access, you cannot enforce the uniqueness from external source, no matter what language you use.

Comment: PHP sends "SELECT" to MySQL. There's a lag involved. MySQL does the job and returns the result. You do some processing with PHP. You query again. Again some small amount of latency is involved. You instruct MySQL to insert. But at this point a record might exist with that value. Now - all that versus one insert, one trip, one error check.

Comment: @axiac +1 for concurrent access. Check-then-insert is bound to go wrong sooner or later.

Comment: In general, for almost all questions of the type "Which is faster, pure SQL or SQL + PHP" the answer will be "pure SQL", because SQL is WAY faster at just about anything than PHP is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maintain a unique column in a database, then use the database mechanisms for that.  Create a unique index or unique constraint on the column.  Work *with* the database, not against it.

Furthermore, there is a major issue with your first approach.  You are introducing a race condition.  Two processes could attempt to insert the same record at the same time.  They would both look at the values in the table and both would see that the insert is okay.  And then both would insert the same value, creating a duplicate.

Of course, there are work-arounds for this, generally involving transactional logic or locking the tables.  Both of these introduce additional overhead, which slows down performance.

Just create a unique column and don't worry about the uniqueness -- the database does the worrying for you.